# Simple Looping / loop in Jquery Templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I am trying to have a simple for loop in jquery templates. Something in the lines of

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
 str += <img src="/images/sw/Star-Orange.png">;
}
```

How do i convert this into the format of..

```
{{each i}}
{{//each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
{{each [1,2,3,4..]}}
    <img src="/images/sw/Star-Orange.png">;
{{/each}}
```

of

```
{{each items}}
    <img src="/images/sw/Star-Orange.png">;
{{/each}}
```

where `items` is an array.

Comment: What do you I do when i dont know the count from before, say in our case

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
 str += <img src="/images/sw/Star-Orange.png">;
}

where n is a variable